# Changing State variable in react when leaving and entering an image element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change a state variable to 'true' when it enters an image element and to 'false' when it leaves an image element. However, when I enter my image element, the setState function does the opposite of what I want. When I enter the element it gets set to 'false' and when I leave the element it gets set to 'true'. Can anyone please help me with this problem? My code is down below:

```
import React from 'react'
import Waldo from '../images/waldo.jpg'

//Note: https://www.chestysoft.com/imagefile/javascript/get-coordinates.asp -- coordinates of image 

export default function Picture() {


    // I need to create a drop down menu 
    // Create a state variable that stores whether the mouse is above the waldo image
    const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = React.useState(true)
    const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)
    const [xPos, setXPos] = React.useState(0)
    const [yPos, setYPos] = React.useState(0)

    const changeMouseOverTrue = () => {
        setMouseOver(true)    
    }

    const changeMouseOverFalse = () => {
        setMouseOver(false)
        
    }

    function changeClick(){
        setClicked(prevClicked => !prevClicked)
        console.log(clicked)
    }

    // Find position of image from its parent
    function FindPosition(oElement) {
        if (typeof (oElement.offsetParent) != "undefined") {
            for (var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent) {
                posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
                posY += oElement.offsetTop;
            }
            return [posX, posY];
        }
        else {
            return [oElement.x, oElement.y];
        }
    }

    // Find position of where the user clicked 
    function GetCoordinates(e) {
        var PosX = 0;
        var PosY = 0;
        var ImgPos;
        ImgPos = FindPosition(myImg);
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            PosX = e.pageX;
            PosY = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
            PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
                + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        let PositionX = PosX
        let PositionY = PosY
        PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
        PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];

        let position = [PosX, PosY];
        setXPos(PositionX);
        setYPos(PositionY);
        return 
    }
    var myImg = document.getElementById("waldo-image");
    
    return (
        
        <div className="image-container">
            <img 
                src={Waldo} 
                className="waldo-image" 
                id="waldo-image"
                onMouseLeave={changeMouseOverFalse}
                onMouseEnter={changeMouseOverTrue}
                onMouseDown={GetCoordinates}
                onClick={changeClick}
            />
            <div 
                className="dropdown-menu"
                // style = {{display: clicked ? "flex" : "none" }}
                style={clicked ? { display: 'flex', position: 'absolute', top: `${yPos}px`, left:`${xPos}px` } : {display:'none'}}

            >
                <button>Robin</button>
                <button>Fred Flinstone</button>
                <button>Johnny Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: State updates are asynchronous. You will have to show us how you are using `mouseOver`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I haven't used mouseOver for anything beyond checking to see if it set to the correct value onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave. I have updated my post to include all of the code for the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow. I couldnt reproduce your error. After making sure the code actally runs, it did work as you presumably intended:

```js
export default function Picture() {
    const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = React.useState(false)
     const changeMouseOverTrue = () => {
        setMouseOver(true)    
      }

    const changeMouseOverFalse = () => {
        setMouseOver(false)
      }  
  return (
    <div className="image-container">
          <span>{mouseOver?"true":"false"}</span>
          <img 
              src={'https://picsum.photos/200/300'} 
              className="waldo-image" 
              id="waldo-image"
              onMouseLeave={changeMouseOverFalse}
              onMouseEnter={changeMouseOverTrue}
          />
    </div>)
}
```

Ideally, when asking a question, please also provide a link to a jsfiddle or stackblitz example of what your current code is, that makes it easier for people like me to try to find the solution, here is a link on stackblitz to a working example using the code above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hqcujn?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. It seems that when I console.log mouseOver it gives me the opposite of what I want. However, when I add the value to a span element like you did, it gives me the correct value. Thank you for your help. Also, I will add the jsfiddle next time I ask a question.